# Dask map_partitions returns a dask.Series instead of dask.DataFrame

Tags: python, bigdata, dask, dask-dataframe, data-partitioning

I am having some issues understanding why I am getting a `dask.Series` back instead of a `dask.DataFrame` when using Dask's `map_partitions()`

**ddf** is one of several large data sets split-loaded as a dask.DataFrame split into 1000 partitions. The whole data has >300 million rows and something like 30 columns.
I am attempting to reshape the data from wide to long.
I have 2 other custom functions that I need to apply using `map_partitions()`, but it seems like I am getting this in all of them. For now, I am trying to resolve this one...

the simple example for `ddf`:

| 'id' | cause_a | cause_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 'aaaa' | 'dddd' |
| 12345688 | 'bbbb' | '0000' |

The expected output for `ddf`:

| 'id' | n_cause | cause |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | cause_a | 'aaaa' |
| 12345678 | cause_b | 'dddd' |
| 12345688 | cause_a | 'bbbb' |

```py
def meltcause(df):
    multiple_causes_cols = [col for col in df.columns.values if 'cause' in col]
    keepcols = [col for col in df.columns.values if col not in multiple_causes_cols]
    df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=keepcols, value_vars=multiple_causes_cols,
        var_name='n_cause', value_name='cause')
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    df = df.loc[df['cause']!='0000']
    return df
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(lambda partition_df: meltcause(partition_df),
                               meta=dd.DataFrame).clear_divisions()
```

When I check the type of `ddf` before running `map_partitions()` is a dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
however, after I run it, even though I specify the `meta=dd.DataFrame` it is `dd.dataframe.core.Series`
I am not sure what I am missing. The docs make it seem a lot more straightforward than I am finding it.

PS. If I take a partition (the first with `ddf.partitions[0].compute()`) and use it as a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe, all the functions work. As in, I get the correct dataframe back with:

```py
df = ddf.partitions[0].compute()
df = meltcause(df)
```

I was able to bypass calling `map_partitions()` by extracting the "computations" out of the custom function in the script utilizing Dask, however I found this behavior strange and would still like an answer as to why [dask](/questions/tagged/dask) is returning a Series? What exactly is setting `meta=dask.DataFrame` doing in this case?

Comment: Hi, what happens if you don't put the meta kwarg? Also, why are you using a lambda function instead of just using the function alone?

Comment: `meta` should be a *pandas* dataframe with the correct columns and dtypes of your expected output and few or no rows.

Comment: @mdurant When I changed to `meta=pd.DataFrame` I was getting a dask.Series object. I believe it was a series of the resulting pd.DFs, however I wanted to know if there was a way for Dask to return an actual dask.DataFrame object with each pd.DF as a partition (like the original ddf). I assume the `to_frame()` would do this, but on my test it did now. The docs page for that function was not very clear or helpful to me. Since I found another work around I did that for now, but would still like to expand my understanding of how Dask is operating.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB When I removed the meta kwarg it was giving me the following warning
`UserWarning: 
You did not provide metadata ... please provide the 'meta=' keyword, as described in the map or apply function that you are using.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta=('temp', 'object'))`
and returning a dask.Series, which seemed to contain each partition, but  converting to a dask.DataFrame, it did not work, I wasn't keeping a log for those trials unfortunately.

Comment: No, not the DataFrame class, a specific **instance** of it, with appropriate dtypes